# Rails script not updating all mongoid documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, mongoid

Currently, I have a User object that has a field `realname`. I'm trying to split on the space and convert it to two fields, `first_name` and `last_name`. Below is the script that I wrote to do this:

```
User.all.each do |user| 
  puts "Updating #{user.realname}"
  name = user.realname.split(' ')

  user.first_name = name[0]
  user.last_name = name[1]

  user.save
  puts "Saved #{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"
  sleep(1)
end
```

When I run this using rails runner in my development environment, many of the first half of the users aren't not getting updated. Although the output from the script is perfect, when I look at what is saved in mongo, some users don't have these new fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure those users are valid?

Try using `user.save!` instead of `user.save`.

If you want to save this nevertheless then you can bypass validations by calling:

```
user.save(validate: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for a changed default_scope on your User class.

If the default scope have been changed, then User#All will not mean "all objects available on DB".

Comment: User.all does get those users that were not updated in this case